# Pass HandleOpenURL for the Facebook URL

Tags: iphone

https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent&scope=publish_stream&client_id=%24FBAPPID&local_client_id=%24SUFFIX&redirect_uri=fb%24FBAPPID%24SUFFIX%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&sdk=ios&display=touch

```
- (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

I am calling this method from other class

```
-(void)callMethod{

BOOL bool;

    NSURL *testURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://m.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=254225037982009&client_id=254225037982009&redirect_uri=fb254225037982009%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&sdk=ios&display=touch&type=user_agent&perms=user_birthday%2Cemail&fbconnect=1&sso=iphone-safari&from_login=1&refid=9&_rdr"];
 bool =   [testComponent handleOpenURL:testURL];

if(bool == YES){
NSLOG(@"Return YES");
}
```

}

I am guessing it need to return YES.  but its returning NO.
Can any one advice me when it return YES.
@All

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIApplication's [canOpenURL:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL%3a) to test and see if it can be opened before trying to open it.

It's not clear what exactly you're trying to do, but if you're wanting to open the Facebook app from your app, you need to use Facebook's custom URL scheme which starts with fb://

Comment: return YES if the URL starts with 'fb[ app_id]://authorize and hence was handled.   i given fb134235034985021://authorize //m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent&scope=publish_stream&client_id=%24FBAPPID&local_client_id=%24SUFFIX&redirect_uri=fb%24FBAPPID%24SUFFIX%3A%2F%2Fauthorize&sdk=ios&display=touch